# Can you submit data from a web page to Flurry Analytics?

Tags: mobile, analytics, flurry

We have developed an iPhone, Android, and BlackBerry app for our product.  We also have an ASP.NET MVC mobile website that provides the same content as the native apps for any of the sorry folks who don't have a device that supports one of the native apps.

We are successfully using the Flurry SDKs to submit data for our iPhone, Android, and Blackberry apps but would also like to submit and track the same data for our mobile website.  Each platform has the exact same screens as the other, so it makes sense to have all of the analytic data recorded in the same manner, and reported in the same interface.

We are aware of [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) and [Google Analytics for Mobile](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/web/) but again, we want our clients to be able to view report on all platforms from the same system.

Is it possible to submit data to Flurry without using a native mobile SDK?  It seems they only give you options to add a native application in the "Add an Application" configuration on their site - how would you add a mobile website?

If someone has done this before, I would love to hear the details.  Thanks.

Comment: Flurry Mobile Web SDK readme with some examples: https://github.com/Wizcorp/wizAnalytics/tree/master/api/flurry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flurry released their Mobile Web SDK 1.0.0 on 06/27/2013.

You can download the documentation by creating a new project and choosing "Mobile Web" then visiting the [Download SDK](https://dev.flurry.com/uploadVersionSelectProject.do) page.
The API is in Javascript.

However, Flurry support specified by email that

> The Mobile Web SDK is no longer updated and the support we provide for this
>   SDK is limited.

Comment: Hi @Axel. This may be a little too late, but the option of creating a mobile web application is no longer available on Flurry. Is there anyway that I can still create one?

Comment: I don’t use Flurry on my current projects, I can’t tell if it’s still possible or not.